# Contao: Frontend - Get theme section of another page - not the current page

Tags: php, contao

I would need to reach a custom section by page id (or PageModel Object), but I don't find a way to get the FrontendTemplate. I would like to use it in a dropdown navigation to echo a custom section of the hovered (parent) page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody will search for, the answer is:

```
<?php
    $articles = \ArticleModel::findPublishedByPidAndColumn($id, $column_name);
    echo static::getArticle($articles[0]); // for ex. the first article
?>
```